# Why wait to lop off a bacterial canker?

Tags: fruit-trees, diseases, plums

[image: Possible bacterial canker on young fruiting plum]

There is what I think is bacterial canker on my young, multi-species fruiting plum tree. I bought it from a big box store a year ago and planted it, and I noticed this a few weeks ago. Assuming I'm right, and that this is in fact bacterial canker, my question is: I've seen advice to wait until winter to lop it off, but why should I do so? Why shouldn't I just lop it off now, before it has a chance to spread and get worse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the UK, the recommended time for pruning plum trees is April or July, but definitely not at other times because of the risk of silverleaf disease.

I'm not sure that is canker, and its definitely not bacterial canker at the moment because there's no sign of dampness or oozing from the area. However, the bark has gone for a reason and that area will be more  vulnerable to infection, although it does seem its formed a callous over the area. If you're concerned, you could cut it out now, but you don't say where you are, so its not possible to say whether this is a good time  to prune it out or not - infections and problems and pruning times may vary in different countries.

Comment: Given the "big box store" in the question, the poster is almost certainly in the US or perhaps, Canada.

Comment: What is a big box store?

Comment: Hmmm. Marks and Sparks in the UK? They kind of come in two flavors: a grocery store/pharmacy-apothocary/clothing/household supplies and appliances/candy/seasonal stuff/plants(in spring) store or a lumber/household appliances/paint/tools/hardware/power and hand tools/candy/seasonal stuff/plants(in spring) store. Invariably, the plants are from poor nurseries and the "garden center" staff are very low paid people (often high school students) who know nothing about plants and are expected only to water them. These are putting legitimate nurseries out of business. *SIGH*

Comment: Yes, Jurp is correct. New Jersey, USA. And for what it's worth, I purchased three other fruit trees from a local nursery last weekend.

Comment: @Jurp ah, so more like our Wilkinson's chain then, and Lidl would fit that description, and a few years back, Woolworths - much more down market than M & S, which is only fashion and food.

Comment: @Bamboo. I chose M & S from reading Sophie Kinsella (not the "Shopaholic" series, though), which explains my mistake :)  The name "big box store" comes from these places always selling their goods in literally big windowless boxes.

Comment: Okay, well, it sounds like I should wait until next March or thereabouts to prune it off. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could take a risk and do it now -its only what, 10 days into May, if you're really worried about the tree

Comment: I'll hold off for now, just in case. Thank you for your help!